# How to check which controller a request is coming from?

Tags: httprequest, commerce-cloud

Can anyone give any clues on how I can check if a request is coming from a specific controller? I meant, to meet this requirement:

> As the order model gets loaded whenever the customer has an
> interaction with the order, SFCC should only perform this check ***if the
> request is coming from the checkout controller***.

Comment: Is this an asynchronous call (ajax)? Or a direct page load?

Comment: @ThomasTheunen
It might work for both requests. This example was for a direct page load. If it's from an Ajax call, the path will be a little different (comes with controller-function), so the condition should be like this:


`if (pathRequest.toLowerCase() === 'checkout' || pathRequest.toLowerCase() === 'checkoutshippingservices-updateshippingmethodslist') {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    var path = request.httpHeaders.get('x-is-path_info');
    -> /us/en/checkout

    path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
    -> checkout

    if (path === 'checkout') {
      //do something 
    }
```

Comment: This will only work if this is the same in all locales and if no one ever touches the URL configuration in the Business Manager. So this solution comes with "risks."

Comment: I agree with you, but considering that we are using the default settings in BM and we don't want to add any url parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what controller this is, I would pass a URL parameter "source" with the value of where it comes from in the redirect. This allows for client "manipulation," so it depends on what you are trying to accomplish.